# How to filter out list elements that are indexed after an element that fullfills a condition?

Tags: list, scala, data-structures, higher-order-functions

I have this list:

```
var ls = List("Should be ignored", "X", "test", "test1", "X", "test2")
```

I was wondering if someone knows how I could filter out the elements in the list which are right after the "X" so that the result is:

```
List("test", "test2")
```

So far I have tried:

```
  ls.filter(x => x._2.equals("X"))
```

However that simply bring back this result:

```
List((0,This line should be ignored, because it is before the first predicate), (2,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.), (3,Suspendisse aliquet quis ligula nec tristique.), (5,Donec augue ipsum, mattis et elit vel, convallis convallis dui.), (7,In hac habitasse platea dictums.))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sliding` to get an `Iterator` of every tuple of consecutive elements, and then select the second elements from the tuples in which `"X"` is the first element:

```
val items = List("Should be ignored", "X", "test", "test1", "X", "test2")

items
  .sliding(2)
  .collect { case List("X", item) => item }
  .toList

// res0: List[String] = List(test, test2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might create the new list by unfolding over the given list.

```
var ls = List("Should be ignored", "X", "test", "test1", "X", "test2")

List.unfold(ls){state =>
  val ns = state.dropWhile(_ != "X").drop(1)
  Option.when(ns.nonEmpty)(ns.head->ns.tail)
}
//res0: List[String] = List(test, test2)
```

Should work no matter how many `"X"` elements there are.

But what if the input is `List("A","X","X","X","B")`? Should the result be `List("X","B")` or just `List("B")`? Right now my suggested solution produces the former but it can produce the latter after a very simple modification.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simples solution would be this:

```
def filterAfterX(data: List[String]): List[String] =
  (data lazyZip data.tail).collect {
    case ("X", word) => word
  }.toList
```